# session (Laravel) destroyed come back from other domain in cypress e2e testing

Tags: cypress, automation-testing

session destroyed after disabling chromeWebSecurity on the same test case in Cypress. When come back from another domain then return to the login page instead of the dashboard page.

[Error problem](https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/72722281/240898095-7cd558ae-ac5a-4c85-8a6e-5c83838f1143.mp4)

Session not be destroyed after leaving th origin.